# Mongodb search without special characters

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have such a MongoDB collection:

```
{
...
"vin": "VDF-454s",
...
}
```

How can I get that document searching by  **vdf454s**. In lowercase and without special characters?
Thank you a lot, guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put [\W_]* after each character

```
D[\W_]*B[\W_]*5[\W_]*3
```